# Chrome 16 websockets hybi-17

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to get sockets working with Chrome 16 which is using the latest protocol for it:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17

Server is using node.js and heres the code:

```
var http = require('http'), net = require('net'), crypto = require('crypto');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
});

server.on('connection', function (stream) {
    stream.setEncoding('utf8');
    stream.setTimeout(0);
    stream.setNoDelay(true);
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("****Incoming****\r\n" + data);     
        var securyPattern = /Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)/g;
        var key = securyPattern.exec(data);
        var magic = '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
        var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1');
        sha1.update(key[1] + magic);
        var accept = sha1.digest('base64');
        var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + accept;

        stream.write(response);
        console.log("****Outgoing****\r\n" + response);
    });
});

server.listen(1337, 'xxxxxxx.no-ip.info');
```

The no-ip.info is to my IP and I'm using that adress for my webserver which works fine.

The browser (client) code inside script-tag inside the head:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://xxxxxxx.no-ip.info:1337/"); 

    myWebSocket.onopen = function(evt) {
        alert("open");
        console.log("WebSockets connection opened");
        myWebSocket.send("a test message");
    };

    myWebSocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
        console.log("Got WebSockets message: " + e.data);
    };

    myWebSocket.onclose = function(evt) {
        console.log("WebSockets connection closed");
    };
};
```

The onopen function is never triggered, I found most of this code here on stackoverflow, but changed so it would work with the latest protocol, does anyone know what is wrong with the code? (When I connect it does however print in the CMD the data being sent to it, but in the Chrome console it just says closed connection (never open).

Comment: What do you get if you define a function for `myWebSocket.onerror`?

Comment: It's not being triggered that one too :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know node.js, so it may do this for you but...

Shouldn't your response end with \r\n\r\n? At the very least it looks like your accept header is missing a \r\n...

Comment: Hi. This was the problem and it now connects.
I had tried with \r\n which apparently wasnt enough. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your response is missing a Web-Socket-Protocol header. If the client sends a protocol list (1 or more) then server must choose one and return it in the response.

Also, your response should end in "\r\n\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at http://socket.io ? has both node module and front end

Comment: That looks intresting, but I can't find any download link for it, I'm using windows right now, how can I install it?

Comment: Can you use NPM, the Node Package Manager? http://npmjs.org/ — AFAICT, Node on Windows is still being sorted out.